# JavaScript layout manager?

Tags: javascript, frameworks, javascript-framework, layout-manager

I am looking for a JavaScript layout manager that has support for flexible layouts: nesting, resizing, splitters, collapsible panels etc.

I've seen ExtJS and Dojo but I'm wondering if there are any lightweight variants that excel at this ...

Thanks!

Comment: @Emil Ivanov: Yes, what about it? Is there a library you're thinking of? Thanks :)

Comment: Looking for the same. For a while now. Just to overcome limitations of CSS. I think I'll try writing my own.

Comment: PS: this question may not be "off-topic". There aren't that many "JavaScritpt layout managers" out there, so asking for a light-weight one is pretty specific, and I would not be surprised if there is none. The answers are a bit off topic, though. Isotope, for example, is not a "layout manager".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have your tried jQuery along with the UI.layout plugin?

http://layout.jquery-dev.net/

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co), a plug-in for jQuery?